# Special Characters are becoming ambiguous when using mencoder or ffmpeg

Tags: linux, encoding, ffmpeg, mencoder

i have subtitles encoded in iso-8859-1 at least thats what file -bi says..

They have turkish special characters such as ğ,ü,ş,ç,ö.. When i try this command

```
mencoder source.avi -sub source.srt -o output.avi -oac copy -ovc lavc \
  -lavcopts vbitrate=1200
```

Turkish characters either is not showing or becoming ambiguous. Also i have tried to iconv to convert character encoding to utf-8 also didn't work.

I have tried ffmpeg with `-sub_charenc iso-8859-1`, `-sub_charenc cp1254`, `-sub_charenc iso-8859-9`

they all didn't work when i tried to make .ass file like this

```
ffmpeg -sub_charenc utf8 -i test.srt test1.srt
```

it showed subtitle lines ok on the screen. So i know that it can read lines but i couldn't render video with iso-8859-9(inc. turkish characters) subtitle.

Is someone has any idea how can i do it? People who have done it for their own language may help too. I mean i know that german and spanish has their own special characters.

Comment: Is your libass compiled with harfbuzz support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with using mencoder like this

-sub test.srt -subcp enca:tr:iso-8859-9

I hope this helps.